# Python 3.6 throws error while trying to import Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, pip

**Whenever I try to import tensorflow on my Windows PC, python always throws this error at the console**

> > > import tensorflow

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File 
    "C:\Users\AyushSingh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: 
    disable=unused-import
    File
    "C:\Users\Ayush Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
    File 
    "C:\Users\Ayush Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
    packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
    File 
    "C:\Users\Ayush Singh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site- 
    packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be 
    found.
```

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling tensorflow using pip3

Comment: Have you seen [this github issue](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046)? (I googled "from google.protobuf.pyext import _message ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my log from when I set up tensorflow under windows, in a separate environment. Perhaps this is helpful to you:

```
conda create --name tfpy3p6 python=3.6 -y

conda activate tfpy3p6

conda install -c anaconda cudatoolkit==9.0
conda install -c anaconda cudnn

pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.12.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

conda install ipython
conda install notebook==5.7.5
ipython kernel install --user
```